# My division method won't run. Everything else is fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

super confused why my `division()` method won't run, everything else is fine. I know how stupid simple this is but I'm deadass confused as hell. I have other methods included but iv removed them due to its unneeded, my other methods work with the same exact code just fine, but division it just fails to run.

```
def TudorSelect():
    TaskSelect = input(
        "Please select one of the following tasks to practice; Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, Divison:    "
    )
    global total
    global difficulty
    difficulty = int(
        input("Please select the max value range of your values: 0 - "))
    print(chr(13))
    total = int(input("Total practice questions for this task:    "))
    if TaskSelect == "Addition":
        addition()
    elif TaskSelect == "Subtraction":
        subtraction()
    elif TaskSelect == "Multiplication":
        multiplication()
    elif TaskSelect == "Divison":
        division()

def division():
    for num in range(total):
        global correcttotal
        randvalue1 = random.randint(1, difficulty)
        randvalue2 = random.randint(1, difficulty)
        correctvalue = (randvalue1 / randvalue2)
        print(str(randvalue1), " / ", str(randvalue2))
        uservalue = input()
        if uservalue == str(correctvalue):
            print("Correct")
            correcttotal = correcttotal + 1
        else:
            print("False")
            print("Correct answer is ", str(correctvalue))
    CorrectRate = ((correcttotal) / (total)) * 100
    print("Your total mark is ", str(CorrectRate), "%")
    TudorSelect()
```

Comment: What's the error and which line is it happening?

Comment: This wont make the program fail to run, but your function is doing integer division, so for example 7 / 3 would be 2, which could be frustrating for users.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it "won't run"? What specifically do you do in your attempt to make it run; what happens; and how is that different from what you expect to happen?

Comment: @5zero i suggest you review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: You have tagged this [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] with no indication as to which one you are actually using. Division is one of the things which changed dramatically between the two. Unless you are specifically looking for a cross-version solution (in which case your question should definitely mention this in some more detail) only tag as one or the other.

Comment: Also, probably avoid gratuitous profanity.

Comment: You mis-spelled "divison". After the `elif division` you could at an else stating "inocrrect input".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a misconception about the use of `global`, `global` is used to modify a global variable in a local scope, so trying to make `correcttotal` global is of no use, `correcttotal` is only declared within your function.

So to fix this you need to remove the `global` keyword from your loop, and also define the accumlator `correcttotal` outside your loop, it needs to be alive outside of it to accumalate properly:

```
import random
def TudorSelect():
    TaskSelect = input(
        "Please select one of the following tasks to practice; Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, Divison:    "
    )
    global total
    global difficulty
    difficulty = int(
        input("Please select the max value range of your values: 0 - "))
    print(chr(13))
    total = int(input("Total practice questions for this task:    "))

    if TaskSelect == "Addition":
        addition()
    elif TaskSelect == "Subtraction":
        subtraction()
    elif TaskSelect == "Multiplication":
        multiplication()
    elif TaskSelect == "Divison":
        division()

def division():
    correcttotal = 0
    for num in range(total):
        randvalue1 = random.randint(1, difficulty)
        randvalue2 = random.randint(1, difficulty)
        correctvalue = (randvalue1 / randvalue2)
        print(str(randvalue1), " / ", str(randvalue2))
        uservalue = input()
        if uservalue == str(correctvalue):
            print("Correct")
            correcttotal = correcttotal + 1
        else:
            print("False")
            print("Correct answer is ", str(correctvalue))
    CorrectRate = ((correcttotal) / (total)) * 100
    print("Your total mark is ", str(CorrectRate), "%")
    TudorSelect()

TudorSelect()
```

Now when you run it like this

```
Please select one of the following tasks to practice; Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, Divison:    Divison
Please select the max value range of your values: 0 - 200

Total practice questions for this task:    5
117  /  115
20
False
Correct answer is  1.017391304347826
50  /  6
20
False
Correct answer is  8.333333333333334
64  /  158
10
False
Correct answer is  0.4050632911392405
61  /  109
1.5
False
Correct answer is  0.5596330275229358
66  /  18
3.667
False
Correct answer is  3.6666666666666665
Your total mark is  0.0 %
```

It works properly, also your answer checks are very tight, I'm not a super computer to get to that level of accuracy on floating point part of the answer at the least, I think you need to round the answer first and then compare it with the student answer.

And as a final note, I really do not recommend the use of `global`, why not just pass it as a parameter to your function instead, it will be much more readable and easier to trace.

Comment: thanks a bunch, the reasoning behind is, to be frank, my knowledge of Python is super brief, thanks for the advice though, will do in the future

Comment: Also, when i run this i still get no output when i run my division() method? like quite literally nothing happens, no prompts or print statements.

Comment: how do you run this ? it's a script, you need to try it out in terminal ```python script.py```

Comment: Yeah, I do, I'll run it in python directly and it just still doesn't run, selecting division method just causes my program to crash,

Comment: @5zero you misspelled "division"

Comment: As Moberg pointed out , division is written as 'divison' in your code, you either correct it in code or misspell it in input. I ran the code in the link and it works fine